# Mean of squared sum of normal random variables

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, normal-distribution, means

Let $X_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ and independent. I would like to show that $\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(\sum\limits_{j=1}^i X_j)^2 \rightarrow \infty$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$ in probability. My problem is that the squared sums aren't independent. Does anyone have an idea which theorem or trick could be useful to solve this.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is enough to show that $(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i) ^{2} \to \infty$ in probability because $Y_n \to \infty$ in probability implies $\frac 1n \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}Y_i \to \infty$ in probability.

Now let $Z=\frac 1 {\sqrt {n}} {(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i)}$. Then $Z \sim N(0,\sigma^{2})$. Hence $P((\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i) ^{2}  \leq M)=P(Z^{2} \leq \frac M n) \to 0$ as $ n \to \infty$ for each $M \in (0,\infty)$. This finishes the proof.

Note: $Z_n \to \infty$ in probability iff $Ee^{-Z_n} \to 0$ in probability. Hence $Ee^{-Y_n} \to 0$ in probability  Since $e^{-x}$ is a convex function it follows that $Ee^{-\frac 1 n  \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}Y_i} \leq \frac 1 n \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}Ee^{-Y_i} \to 0$. Hence $\frac 1n \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}Y_i \to \infty$ in probability.

Comment: Is there as well a simple way to show that $Y_n \rightarrow \infty$ implies $\frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n Y_i \rightarrow \infty$ in probability, since it is the core of the answer?

Comment: @WingMan Sorry for the delay in responding to your query. I was on the road for  while. I have edited my answer with a simple proof of the convergence of the averages in probability.